# What are the two symbols in the Google Translate icon

Tags: google-translate

What are the two symbols used in the Google Translate icon????

I've got the "A"... said the ignorant American.

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It is a totally off-topic question about graphical symbols.

Answer (score 17):

Another one is a Chinese character, `文`.

In Chinese, `文` means `text` or `article`, and its pronunciation is similar like `when` in English.